# Minimise risk of errors caused by improper shutdown

Tags: windows-7, ssd, shutdown

We have a touch panel PC set up in an industrial environment where power can be interrupted, without proper time to shut down. A UPS is not an option in this case.

All that will be running on the PC is Windows 7 and our custom application.

I am not sure if it makes any difference but the system drive is a SSD.

Are there any windows settings we should configure to minimise the risk of operating system corruption.

In addition we would like to avoid the message when the computer boots up that the computer has been improperly shut down, with the 20 second timer that we are unable to skip as there is no keyboard on the system.

Comment: why is a UPS not an option?

Comment: This is in a lightweight portable enclosure, the power failures are people not shutting the PC down properly before unplugging.

Comment: does this computer store data?  or is it just to control equipment?

Comment: It does have the capability of datalogging, but this is flushed to disk. Ultimately if they unplug it while logging and it corrupts the log file we dont mind. We are only concerned about damage to the system in the sense of hardware damage or windows corruption (or our executable I suppose)

Comment: Is it custom hardware? Can it be replaced with a lightweight device with a built-in battery, like a laptop or something NUC-class?

Comment: Possibly in the future, but in this case we already have a number of devices in the field. We have not had any issues as of yet, but have had people comment on the prompts when the PC boots up.

Comment: Why NUC Class?.

Comment: Because they're small ("lightweight portable enclosure") and there are existing designs with included batteries.